# Java Spring elasticsearch "Failed to derive xcontent" with @Query

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a custom @Query in one of my elasticsearch repositories because the autoGenerated method didn't use match (instead query_string with analyze_wildcard) and so didn't work for example with spaces. This query looks pretty simple to me so I thought it wouldn't be a problem to write it myself.

```
@Query("\"bool\": { " +
        "   \"filter\": [ " +
        "    {  " +
        "       \"term\": { " +
        "          \"userId.keyword\": \"?0\" " +
        "        } " +
        "    }, " +
        "    {" +
        "       \"match\": { " +
        "          \"content\": \"?1\" " +
        "       }" +
        "     } " +
        "   ] " +
        "  }")
Page<SearchablePageHistory> findAllByUserIdAndContentLike(String userId, String content, Pageable pageable);
```

But when I try to execute that function I get the following error:

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=x_content_parse_exception, reason=Failed to derive xcontent]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177) ~[elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1793) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1770) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1527) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1484) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:970) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.lambda$search$10(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:265) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:351) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.search(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:265) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchStringQuery.execute(ElasticsearchStringQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/history/_search?pre_filter_shard_size=128&typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"}],"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"Failed to derive xcontent"},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:283) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:261) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:235) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1514) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
        ... 124 common frames omitted
```

With debuggin I tracked down the raw Rest-Request that is sent to elasticsearch in org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.java:244 and found that this is the payload sent to the server:

```
{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"wrapper":{"query":"ImJvb2wiOiB7ICAgICJmaWx0ZXIiOiBbICAgICB7ICAgICAgICJ0ZXJtIjogeyAgICAgICAidXNlcklkLmtleXdvcmQiOiAiMzFjMjA5NTktNjg5Zi00YjI4LWExNzctNmQ3ZTQ2YTBhYzMwIiAgICAgIH0gICAgIH0sICAgeyJtYXRjaCI6IHsgICAgImNvbnRlbnQiOiAidGVzdHNzIiAgIH19ICAgIF0gICB9"}},"version":true,"sort":[{"id":{"order":"desc"}}]}
```

With that payload an error is not suprising however I have no idea why there is this weird mumble of characters. I suspect that that is supposed to be my custom query which is not used correctly. I got this payload by debugging into this line:

```
httpResponse = client.execute(context.requestProducer, context.asyncResponseConsumer, context.context, null).get();
```

and then executing:

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(((NByteArrayEntity) ((HttpPost) ((HttpAsyncMethods.RequestProducerImpl) context.requestProducer).request).entity).buf).toString()
```

These are my imports and the classname that I use in the Repository-Class:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public interface SearchablePageHistoryRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<SearchablePageHistory, Integer> {
    Page<SearchablePageHistory> findAllByUserId(String userId, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("\"bool\": { " +
        "   \"filter\": [ " +
        "    {  " +
        "       \"term\": { " +
        "          \"userId.keyword\": \"?0\" " +
        "        } " +
        "    }, " +
        "    {" +
        "       \"match\": { " +
        "          \"content\": \"?1\" " +
        "       }" +
        "     } " +
        "   ] " +
        "  }")
    Page<SearchablePageHistory> findAllByUserIdAndContentLike(String userId, String content, Pageable pageable);
}
```

All other queries where I don't use @Query work fine without a problem. I have no idea what I am doing wrong since my example seems very similar to the one given in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hard facepalm, I found my error -> still gonna leave this post up in case someone else stumbles across the same problem since the error message is not very helpful in my opinion.

I simply forgot the surrounding brackets around the outside of the query:

changing this:

```
@Query("\"bool\": { " +
        "   \"filter\": [ " +
        "    {  " +
        "       \"term\": { " +
        "          \"userId.keyword\": \"?0\" " +
        "        } " +
        "    }, " +
        "    {" +
        "       \"match\": { " +
        "          \"content\": \"?1\" " +
        "       }" +
        "     } " +
        "   ] " +
        "  }")
    Page<SearchablePageHistory> findAllByUserIdAndContentLike(String userId, String content, Pageable pageable);
```

to this:

```
    @Query("{\"bool\": { " +
        "   \"filter\": [ " +
        "    {  " +
        "       \"term\": { " +
        "          \"userId.keyword\": \"?0\" " +
        "        } " +
        "    }, " +
        "    {" +
        "       \"match\": { " +
        "          \"content\": \"?1\" " +
        "       }" +
        "     } " +
        "   ] " +
        "  }}")
Page<SearchablePageHistory> findAllByUserIdAndContentLike(String userId, String content, Pageable pageable);
```

solved the problem.

**Addition:**

```
"ImJvb2wiOiB7ICAgICJmaWx0ZXIiOiBbICAgICB7ICAgICAgICJ0ZXJtIjogeyAgICAgICAidXNlcklkLmtleXdvcmQiOiAiMzFjMjA5NTktNjg5Zi00YjI4LWExNzctNmQ3ZTQ2YTBhYzMwIiAgICAgIH0gICAgIH0sICAgeyJtYXRjaCI6IHsgICAgImNvbnRlbnQiOiAidGVzdHNzIiAgIH19ICAgIF0gICB9"
```

is a wrapper query, that's a base64 encoded string conataining

```
""bool": {    "filter": [     {       "term": {       "userId.keyword": "31c20959-689f-4b28-a177-6d7e46a0ac30"      }     },   {"match": {    "content": "testss"   }}    ]   }"
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much for leaving this up, you saved me what would likely have been a few hours of pain!

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue and was actually the absence of bracket

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30432717)